# targeting the last item in an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, audio

I got a function that's half working:

```
function prevTrack() {
    if (playlist_index == (playlist.length - 0)) {
        playlist_index = -1;
    } else {
        playlist_index--;
    }
    playlist_status.innerHTML = playlist[playlist_index];
    audio.src = dir + playlist[playlist_index] + ext;
    audio.play();
}
```

I'm sure the error is in the `playlist_index = -1;`
can anyone please tell me how to target the last item in the array?
so it would be `playlist_index = ???;`

Comment: It looks like you're trying to make playlist_index start over at 0 when it goes above the last valid index. Is that right?

Comment: Im trying to get it so if the prevbtn is pressed and the song playing is the first song in the playlist array, it goes to the last song of the array, I hope that makes sense :)

Comment: This function is for the nextbtn and its working as it should:
 function switchTrack(next){
        if(playlist_index == (playlist.length -1)) {
           playlist_index = 0;
        } else {
            playlist_index++;
        }

Comment: this code works for the 'nextbtn' when the the last track is playing and the nextbtn is pressed it goes to the first song, the line playlist_index = 0; executes and it goes to the first track, im trying to do the opposite with the 'prevbtn' 
if(playlist_index ==  (playlist.length -0)){
playlist_index = -1; (i thought this would make the playlist index go to the last song in the array, but its not working.
 i thought the code playlist_index = -1; would do it, but its not!

Comment: I think `playlist_index == (playlist.length - 0)` should be `playlist_index == 0` and `playlist_index = -1;` should be `playlist_index = playlist.length - 1;`.

Comment: Rocky Sim... you are a legend!!
its working hurray, been at it for a week now!

Answer (score 1):

Setting the index to -1 to get the last element reminds me of python ... in any case that doesn't work in JS. You have to set the index to `playlist.length - 1`.

Comment: if(playlist_index == 0) {
           playlist_index = (playlist.length -1);
that fixed it,

Answer (score 1):

i think `playlist_index = playlist.legth - 1`

Comment: i tried that one my bro... no champagne.
Im struggling to understand, why this code works:
if(playlist_index == (playlist.length -1)) {
playlist_index = 0;
this code works, if the audio playing is the last object in the array, it goes to the first object.
so, how can i make it work but in reverse
if(playlist_index == (playlist.length -0)) {
playlist_index = -1;    this line here doesnt seem to work

Comment: In the first case you're saying "if (lastIndex) go firstIndex" but in the second case you're saying "if (never) go oneBeforeFirstIndex". The "if (never)" is because `playlist_index == playlist.length` will never be true (unless playlist_index is allowed to get bigger than it should). `playlist.length - 1` is the largest valid index.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to set the playlist_index to the last item in the array if the index is zero or the first item in the array?

```
const playlist_index = playlist_index === 0
  ? playlist_index = plalist.length - 1
  : playlist_index--;
```

or

```
const playlist_index = playlist_index === firstValueOfArray
  ? playlist_index = playlist.length - 1
  : playlist_index--;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to make the index go "around the world" so to speak. There is an easy way to do that with the modulo `%` operator.

```js
const list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for (let offset = 0; offset < 10; offset++) {
  const item = list[offset % list.length];
  console.log(item);  
}
```

so you can replace

```
if (playlist_index == (playlist.length - 0)) {
    playlist_index = -1;
} else {
    playlist_index--;
}
```

with

```
playlist_index = (playlist.length + playlist_index - 1) % playlist.length;
```